# Find the corresponding analytic function $f(z)=u(x,y)+i v(x,y).$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $f(z)=u+iv$ when $u-v$ is given. I tried taking partial derivatives of $u-v$ w.r.t $x$ and $y$, but I am unable to proceed from there.

Comment: Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to determine $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$.

Comment: @Daniel, how can we determine du/dx or du/dy? Because u and v are not given separately. only u-v is given.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) tell you that:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(u-v)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(u-v)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
From this you can obtain $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, and consequently $u$ and $v$.

Comment: If It is not given that the function  is analytic, how to proceed?